# 'time' scale type in vega not working for javascript Date

Tags: javascript, vega

Using the vega charting library, I'm dynamically loading my data from a javascript object. Values from that object contain a javascript date and an amount, for example :

```
[
  {date: new Date(2000, 0, 1), amount: 3}, 
  {date: new Date(2001, 0, 1), amount: 7}, 
  {date: new Date(2002, 0, 1), amount: 5}
]
```

A scale type of `ordinal` works fine but the scale type `time` gives me the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: ((intermediate value)(intermediate value) , group.scale(...)).rangeBand is not a function
```

How should I format my dates? (I tried to change the `format.parse` in the chart specification but it's not changing anything (I'm not parsing the data but directly loading it from a javascript object)).

The end goal is to display a subset of the dates on the x axis to avoid overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

The `time` scales in vega work on epoch timestamps, which are integers and not Dates.

It's very easy to obtain them from a JavaScript Date instance, simply apply `getTime()` (or `valueOf()`) on them

```
[
  {date: new Date(2000, 0, 1).getTime(), amount: 3}, 
  {date: new Date(2001, 0, 1).getTime(), amount: 7}, 
  {date: new Date(2002, 0, 1).getTime(), amount: 5}
]
```

---

I would like to add that the strength and nature of Vega specifications are to be serializable, i.e. you can write them as a string (or a JSON more precisely). Hence a `Date` instance wouldn't make sense as it is a complex prototype, so you can think these timestamps as serializations of Dates.